# Como guardar os dados numa variável e usar depois numa query?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma combobox preenchida com dados do banco de dados (nome de médico), de onde escolho um nome, mas queria gravar noutra tabela do banco o `id_medico` e não o nome.

Pensei em usar um `SELECT` para ir buscar o `id`, guardar essa informação numa variável e depois usar essa variável no `INSERT`, mas não sei como encaixar isso no meu código. Podem-me ajudar?

A combobox é preenchida com este código:

```
....

$dbconn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname)or die("Failed to connect to database:" . mysqli_error($dbconn));
$query = "SELECT nome FROM Medicos";
$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
$result = mysqli_num_rows($data);       

?>
&nbsp &nbsp<label for="cbMedicos">Selecione um M&eacute;dico</label>
<select id="cbMedicos" name="cbMedicos">
<option>Selecione...</option>

 <?php while($prod = $data->fetch_assoc()) { 
    echo '<option value="'.$prod['nome'].'">'.$prod['nome'].'</option>';
 }
 ?>    
 </select>
```

O meu código para já é:

```
$dbconn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysql_select_db($dbname);


if (isset($_POST['botao_marcar_consulta']))
{

    $hora_inicio= trim($_POST['txthora_inicio']); 
    $hora_fim = trim($_POST['txthora_fim']);
    $medicos = trim($_POST['cbMedicos']);

     $sql = "INSERT INTO Consulta_marcada (hora_inicio, hora_fim ) VALUES ('".$hora_inicio."', '".$hora_fim."')";


  if(mysql_query($sql))
 {
 echo "<script>alert('Dados inseridos com sucesso');</script>";
 }
 else
{
echo "<script>alert('FAILED TO INSERT ".mysql_error()."');</script>";
}
}
```

Comment: Será interessante você ler: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/5878)

Comment: `$_POST['cbMedicos']` é o nome ou o `id` do médico? Em qual tabela você precisa salvar esse valor?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss $_POST['cbMedicos'] é o nome escolhido da combobox, na tabela consulta _marcada. E tenho o nome dos medicos e o respetivo id na tabela Medicos

Comment: Você não consegue já armazenar o valor do `id` no combobox ao invés do nome? Como você está fazendo ele? Tem como colocá-lo na pergunta?

Comment: Já editei a pergunta... eu quero que na combobox apareça o nome, o id eu utilizo na tabela consulta_marcada para fazer a ligação entre tabelas.

Comment: Ok, basta você fazer `'<option value="'.$prod['id'].'">'.$prod['nome'].'</option>'`. Assim será exibido o nome do médico, mas o valor `$_POST['cbMedicos']` já será o `id` do médico selecionado. Evitará você ter que fazer outra consulta no banco de dados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu HTML, troque o valor do atributo `value` para o `id`:

```
<label for="cbMedicos">Selecione um Médico</label>
<select id="cbMedicos" name="cbMedicos">
    <option>Selecione...</option>
    <?php while($prod = $data->fetch_assoc()) { 
        echo '<option value="'.$prod['id'].'">'.$prod['nome'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>    
</select>
```

> Para tal é necessário adicionar a coluna `id` na consulta: `SELECT id, nome FROM Medicos`.

O valor que será exibido para o usuário continuará sendo `$prod['name']`, mas o valor que será passado ao PHP em `$_POST['cbMedicos']` será o valor do `id` do médico selecionado. Desta forma, ao invés de você precisar fazer a busca no banco de dados para descobrir o `id`, basta inserí-lo diretamente. Algo como:

```
$hora_inicio= trim($_POST['txthora_inicio']); 
$hora_fim = trim($_POST['txthora_fim']);
$medicos = intval($_POST['cbMedicos']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO Consulta_marcada (hora_inicio, hora_fim, id_medico) VALUES ('".$hora_inicio."', '".$hora_fim."', ".$medicos.")";
```

Comment: @AndersinCarlosWoss para mudar para o mysqli, teria que alterar alguma coisa, para além da primeira linha? Ficaria só assim: $dbconn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname)or die("Failed to connect to database:" . mysqli_error($dbconn));

Comment: @IsabelSousa só seguir a lógica que você utilizou para selecionar os médicos. Neste arquivo você já utilizou `mysqli`.

Answer (score 1):

Faça as seguintes alterações no seu código:

1. Para buscar o médico

   ```
   $query = "SELECT id, nome FROM Medicos";
   ```
2. Na exibição dos dados no médico no combobox

   ```
   <?php 
   while($prod = $data->fetch_assoc()) { 
       echo '<option value="'.$prod['id'].'">'.$prod['nome'].'</option>';
   }
   ?>
   ```
3. E na hora de gravar dos dados

   ```
   $hora_inicio= trim($_POST['txthora_inicio']); 
   $hora_fim = trim($_POST['txthora_fim']);
   $id_medico = trim($_POST['cbMedicos']);

   $sql = "INSERT INTO Consulta_marcada (hora_inicio, hora_fim, medico_id) VALUES ('".$hora_inicio."', '".$hora_fim."','".$id_medico."')";
   ```

Se a sua tabela no banco `consulta_marcada` não tiver *foreign key* `id_medico`, você terá que adicionar.

Futuramente você precisará exibir qual consulta marcada cada médico contếm. Poderá fazer assim:

```
SELECT 
me.nome, cm.hora_inicio, cm.hora_fim
FROM
    consulta_marcada AS cm
        INNER JOIN
    medico AS me ON cm.id_medico = me.id
WHERE id_medico = $id['id_medico'];
```

Comente caso tiver problemas.

Comment: No caso, a coluna `id` de `Consulta_marcada` não é o `id` do médico. O que está sendo feito é uma relação de 1 para muitos entre a tabela `Medicos` e `Consulta_marcada`, onde a coluna `id_medico` da segunda é denominada chave estrangeira. Se você gravar o `id` do médico como `id` da consulta, você não poderá ter mais que uma consulta por médico.

Comment: Obrigado por me alertar o erro.

Comment: Faltou alterar no `insert`, no passo 3, que seria o ponto mais crítico.

Comment: Obrigado. Aproveitei e revisei o comentário como um todo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função fetch_assoc() do mysqli para buscar dados do banco:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM <nome_da_tabela> WHERE tabela_nome_do_medico = <nome_do_medico>";

$res = $con->query($sql);

if ($res) {
   while ($linha = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
      $id_medico = $linha['tabela_id_do_medica'];
   }
}
```

Comment: E se tiver médicos com mesmo nome?

Comment: Então o ideal seria buscar pelo ID, que é um valor sempre único

Comment: Exatamente, vide comentários da pergunta.

Comment: Nossa, nem tinha reparado, obrigado pela correção.